# convert sql-request to datatables-type request

Tags: php, mysql

With clean php I used this request:

```
SELECT ucp_request.id, ucp_request.admin_time, ucp_request.admin_time_id, 
ucp_request.create_time,(SELECT login FROM users WHERE 
id=ucp_request.admin_time_id), characters.name, users.login FROM ucp_request 
LEFT JOIN characters ON characters.id=ucp_request.characterid LEFT JOIN users 
ON characters.userid=users.id WHERE ucp_request.status=1
```

As you can see, there are a lot of `left join` and `where` clauses.

I want to convert this request to datatables.net-type requests. It has difficult structure of server-side processing and I can't understand how to do this.

Structure of the table (example):

```
№  ||      Name     || Account ||    Time     || Action
--------------------------------------------------------
1  || John_Johnson  ||  John   || 01.01 01:01 || Check
2  || William_Smith ||  Will   || 01.02 05:15 || Check
```

where `№` is `ucp_request.id`, `name` is `characters.id=ucp_request.characterid`, `account` is `characters.userid=users.id`, `time` is formatted `ucp_request.create_time` and `action` is a button with `ucp_request.admin_time`,`ucp_request.admin_time_id` using.

So I tried this:

**HTML PAGE:**

```
...
<div class="material-datatables">
    <table id="ucprequests" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" 
    cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>№</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>№</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th class="text-right">Action</th>
            </tr>
       </tfoot>
       <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="dataTables_empty">Loading</td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
...
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.datatables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ucprequests').DataTable({
        "aProcessing": true,
        "aServerSide": true,
        "ajax": "../admin/server-responce.php",
        responsive: true,
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
        });
var table = $('#datatables').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

**SERVER-RESPONCE.PHP:**

```
<?php
/*
 * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
 * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine, 2012 - Chris Wright
 * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

/* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
 * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
 */
$aColumns = array( 'id', 'characterid', 'userid', 'create_time');

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "ucp_request";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']       = "root";
$gaSql['password']   = "";
$gaSql['db']         = "database";
$gaSql['server']     = "localhost";


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

/*
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
{
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
}


/*
 * MySQL connection
 */
if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
}

if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
}


/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
$sOrder = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
{
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}


/*
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTable
";
$rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);

while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

In php file I can't deal with `where` clause (if I add `status=1` to `$sWhere` and `status` to `$aColumns` array, clause works, but at `action` outputs 1). Also can't imagine how to use `LEFT JOIN` and multiple `where` clauses there.

Answer (score 0):

Simple query for Mysql:

```
SELECT 
  ucp_request.id, 
  ucp_request.admin_time, 
  ucp_request.admin_time_id, 
  ucp_request.create_time,
  (SELECT login FROM users WHERE id=ucp_request.admin_time_id) AS admin_login, 
  characters.name, 
  users.login 
FROM 
  ucp_request, characters, users 
WHERE 
  characters.id=ucp_request.characterid
AND 
  characters.userid=users.id 
AND 
  ucp_request.status=1
```

Comment: Tried that, it returns nothing for `name` and `account` columns in the table.